# Unable to opening a Menu Item...VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

Whats wrong with the code:

I am trying to open a Menu Item on a webpage ...

```
Do While IE.Busy Or IE.ReadyState <> 4: Loop ' opening the third webpage
  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:01:10"))
  Set HTMLDoc3 = IE.Document

  With HTMLDoc3
  Set objCollection_2 = HTMLDoc3.getElementById("reportsmenucomponent") 'Selecting the MENU Item
  objCollection_2.Click ' Click on the menu Item.
  End With
  End Sub
```

The error message reads "**Object Required**".... What other objects can be used to recover the ID for Menu Item?? By object required what does it mean ...is it not able to read the ID "**reportsmenucomponent**" or the **getelementbyid**??

Comment: [Duplicating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37734725/what-is-the-vba-code-to-open-a-menu-component-and-then-select-an-item) question is frowned upon.

Comment: What's happens if you call ie.document.getelementbyid("reportsmenucomponent").click? The other code really isn't needed.

Comment: Show your code. The page probably hasn't finished loading. Are you going to delete duplicate question?

Comment: @Ryan when I do : ie.document.getelementbyid("reportsmenucomponent").click ....I get the error message the object does not support the property or method...run time error 438
Also,Deleted the duplicate code.

Comment: Try printing out the TypeName of ie, like TypeName(ie). What do you get? Dbmitch has a point, perhaps the page hasn't finished loading or something else.

Comment: I did Dim t1 as String ..... t1= TypeName(IE). It gives t1 = "Iwebrowser2"..... what does this mean?....TypeName should return the data type.  This is my third page...My first webpage is entering login credential....on second webpagei selectfrom a drop down menu...and then on the third webpage I am trying to select from menu Item...........
Also, I have added a wait command Application.   Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:0:21"))  after the while loop

Comment: Does it matter if the developer tab now on the third web page is in JavaScript and till second webpage it was in html?..... will the object .click work for the JavaScript menuitems??

Comment: What des the ItemUrl represent here againt the activity wizard : /reports/depositsactivitywizardnew.esp ?? can I use this to directly navigate to the next page? Like IE Navigate ".../reports/depositsactivitywizardnew.esp"

Comment: `GetElementByID` is not supported by some earlier versions of InternetExplorer.Application class.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution:
It was a Javascript .... so the webpage kept loding with same URL link.... But the menuotem url on the developer tab had a parsed linked... I just concatenated MenuItem URL with the main URL link to deblink it to the next page.

IE Navigate "http://..../parsed URL"